# Добавление фрагмента

Tags: android-fragment, android

Я использую фрагмент, на весь экран там список.

Как я могу разделить экран на две части при нажатии на элемент списка? 
То есть он нажимает на элемент списка и на верхней части на полэкрана появлялись какие-то данные касательно этого элемента, а список из первого фрагмента оставался на месте, но уже на полэкрана?

Как можно такое сделать?

Comment: по клику менять размер контейнера с фрагментом

Comment: @gcoder а что делать дальше, как подставить и как поменять размер?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить в контейнер

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, mFragment)
                        .commit();
```

Поменять размер

```
private void changeWidthTo(FrameLayout frame, int newWidth) {
    if (frame.getWidth() != newWidth) {
        frame.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
        frame.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Вместо размера менять видимость

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```